# SwiftUI: Why do I get the " 'nil' requires a contextual type " with Xcode 11.3 but it worked in Xcode 11.2?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I had the following declaration in a `view` where `SpecialData` is a `Codable`, `Hashable` `struct`:

```
struct SpecialData: Codable, Hashable {
    var id: Int = 0
    var data: String = ""
}
```

```
@State private var data: SpecialData = nil
```

and it compiled in Xcode 11.2

now I get this error: `nil' requires a contextual type`

I know that I need to make the variable an optional:

```
@State private var data: SpecialData? = nil
```

What did change and why did they change it? Was this not intended in the first place?

EDIT: Couldn't find anything in the release notes.

Comment: I'd say that's correct error.